# Category wise value assignment in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In my data frame I have two columns. Emp_id and city. Total size of the data frame is 3.2 million with multiple city names. The data frame looks like -

```
emp_id         city
  2            New York
  3            Houston
  6            Dallas
  7            New York
  11           Dallas
  12           Austin
  13           San Jose
  14           Boston
  15           Boston
  16           Columbus
  24           Austin
  30           Austin
```

My final Output looks like -

```
emp_id         city              present
  2            New York             1
  3            Houston              0
  6            Dallas               1
  7            New York             1
  11           Dallas               1
  12           Austin               0
  13           San Jose             0
  14           Boston               1
  15           Boston               1
  16           Columbus             0
  24           Austin               0
  30           Austin               0
```

I have done so far -

```
df['present'] = np.where(df.loc[df['city'].isin(['New York','Dallas','Boston'])],1,0)
```

I want to consider only 3 cities to '1' and rest of the city is '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['present'] = np.where(df['city'].isin(['New York','Dallas','Boston']),1,0)
```